Cannot Decrypt the Encrypted message
I'm working on implementing a custom cryptographic algorithm and I'm encountering an issue where the output of my encryption and decryption processes doesn't match the expected results. Specifically, I'm not able to correctly decrypt the ciphertext back to the original plaintext.
Block Size:
Input/Output Block Size: 128 bits (16 bytes)
Key Generation:
Initial Key: A 128-bit key is used to generate 16 round keys.
Round Key Generation: The initial key is processed through a key expansion algorithm to produce 16 round keys. Each round key is derived by applying a fixed transformation to the previous round key.
Encryption Process:
Initial State: The plaintext is divided into two halves (L0, R0) of 64 bits each.
Rounds: The encryption process consists of 16 rounds. In each round:
Round Key Application: The round key is XORed with the right half (R).
Feistel Function: A Feistel function is applied to the result, involving substitution and permutation.
Swap: The left and right halves are swapped for the next round.
Final State: After 16 rounds, the final output is obtained by concatenating the left and right halves.
I’m encountering issues where the decrypted output does not match the original plaintext. Despite following the algorithm and applying the round keys correctly, the decrypted text is incorrect or empty.
What I've Tried:
-Verified key generation and round key application.
-Checked the implementation of the substitution, permutation, and other operations.
-Debugged step-by-step to ensure each operation is applied correctly.
Thank you
def pad(plaintext, block_size):
    padding_length = block_size - (len(plaintext) % block_size)
    padding = bytes([padding_length] * padding_length)
    return plaintext + padding

def unpad(padded_plaintext):
    padding_length = padded_plaintext[-1]
    return padded_plaintext[:-padding_length]

def key_expansion(key):
    # Ensure key is 16 bytes for 128-bit key
    if len(key) != 16:
        raise ValueError("Key must be 16 bytes long for 128-bit key")

    # Convert key into an integer for processing
    K = int.from_bytes(key, byteorder='big')
    round_keys = []

    # Generate round keys
    for i in range(17):
        # Calculate round key by rotating and applying transformations
        round_key = (K ^ (i * 0x1B)) % (1 << 128) 
        round_keys.append(round_key.to_bytes(16, byteorder='big'))

    return round_keys

CP_TABLE = [0, 32, 1, 33, 2, 34, 3, 35, 4, 36, 5, 37, 6, 38, 7, 39, 8, 40, 9, 41, 10, 42, 11, 43, 12, 44, 13, 45, 14, 46, 15, 47, 16, 48, 17, 49, 18, 50, 19, 51, 20, 52, 21, 53, 22, 54, 23, 55, 24, 56, 25, 57, 26, 58, 27, 59, 28, 60, 29, 61, 30, 62, 31, 63]

FP_TABLE = [57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5, 63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 0, 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6]


def permute(block, table):
    permuted_block = 0
    for index, bit_pos in enumerate(table):
        permuted_block |= ((block >> bit_pos) & 1) << index
    return permuted_block


SBOX = [
    0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
    0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
    0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
    0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
    0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
    0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
    0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
    0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
    0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
    0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
    0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
    0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08,
    0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a,
    0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e,
    0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf,
    0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
]

INV_SBOX = [SBOX.index(x) for x in range(256)]
INV_CP_TABLE = [CP_TABLE.index(i) for i in range(64)]
INV_FP_TABLE = [FP_TABLE.index(i) for i in range(64)]

def sub_bytes_8(state):
    return [SBOX[b] for b in state]

def shift_rows_8(state):
    return [
        state[0], state[1], state[2], state[3],
        state[4], state[5], state[6], state[7]
    ]

def gf_mult(a, b):
    p = 0
    hi_bit_set = 0
    for _ in range(8):
        if b & 1:
            p ^= a
        hi_bit_set = a & 0x80
        a <<= 1
        if hi_bit_set:
            a ^= 0x1b
        b >>= 1
    return p % 256

def mix_columns_8(state):
    result = [0] * 8
    for c in range(2):
        col = state[c*4:(c+1)*4]
        result[c*4] = gf_mult(2, col[0]) ^ gf_mult(3, col[1]) ^ col[2] ^ col[3]
        result[c*4+1] = col[0] ^ gf_mult(2, col[1]) ^ gf_mult(3, col[2]) ^ col[3]
        result[c*4+2] = col[0] ^ col[1] ^ gf_mult(2, col[2]) ^ gf_mult(3, col[3])
        result[c*4+3] = gf_mult(3, col[0]) ^ col[1] ^ col[2] ^ gf_mult(2, col[3])
    return result

def add_round_key(state, round_key):
    round_key_bytes = list(round_key)
    return [b ^ round_key_bytes[i] for i, b in enumerate(state)]



def encrypt_block_8(block, round_keys):
    block = int.from_bytes(block, byteorder='big')
    block = permute(block, CP_TABLE)
    block = block.to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')
    state = list(block)
    print(f"Initial State: {state}")
    state = add_round_key(state, round_keys[0])
    print(f"After Add Round Key: {state}")
    for i in range(1, 17):
        state = sub_bytes_8(state)
        state = shift_rows_8(state)
        state = mix_columns_8(state)
        state = add_round_key(state, round_keys[i])
        print(f"After Round {i}: {state}")
    block = int.from_bytes(state, byteorder='big')
    block = permute(block, FP_TABLE)
    return block.to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')

def encrypt_message(message, key):
    block_size = 8  # 64-bit block size = 8 bytes
    padded_message = pad(message.encode('utf-8'), block_size)
    round_keys = key_expansion(key)
    
    ciphertext = b''
    for i in range(0, len(padded_message), block_size):
        block = padded_message[i:i+block_size]
        ciphertext += encrypt_block_8(block, round_keys)
    
    return ciphertext

def inv_mix_columns_8(state):
    result = [0] * 8
    for c in range(2):
        col = state[c*4:(c+1)*4]
        result[c*4] = gf_mult(14, col[0]) ^ gf_mult(11, col[1]) ^ gf_mult(13, col[2]) ^ gf_mult(9, col[3])
        result[c*4+1] = gf_mult(9, col[0]) ^ gf_mult(14, col[1]) ^ gf_mult(11, col[2]) ^ gf_mult(13, col[3])
        result[c*4+2] = gf_mult(13, col[0]) ^ gf_mult(9, col[1]) ^ gf_mult(14, col[2]) ^ gf_mult(11, col[3])
        result[c*4+3] = gf_mult(11, col[0]) ^ gf_mult(13, col[1]) ^ gf_mult(9, col[2]) ^ gf_mult(14, col[3])
    return result

def inv_sub_bytes_8(state):
    return [INV_SBOX[b] for b in state]

def inv_shift_rows_8(state):
    return [
        state[0], state[1], state[2], state[3],
        state[4], state[5], state[6], state[7]
    ]

def decrypt_block_8(block, round_keys):
    block = int.from_bytes(block, byteorder='big')
    block = permute(block, INV_FP_TABLE)
    block = block.to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')
    state = list(block)
    state = add_round_key(state, round_keys[16])
    for i in range(15, 0, -1):
        state = inv_mix_columns_8(state)
        state = inv_shift_rows_8(state)
        state = inv_sub_bytes_8(state)
        state = add_round_key(state, round_keys[i])
    state = add_round_key(state, round_keys[0])
    block = int.from_bytes(state, byteorder='big')
    block = permute(block, INV_CP_TABLE)
    return block.to_bytes(8, byteorder='big')

def decrypt_message(ciphertext, key):
    block_size = 8  # 64-bit block size = 8 bytes
    round_keys = key_expansion(key)
    
    plaintext = b''
    for i in range(0, len(ciphertext), block_size):
        block = ciphertext[i:i+block_size]
        plaintext += decrypt_block_8(block, round_keys)
        print("Plain Text: ", plaintext.hex)
    
    return unpad(plaintext).decode('utf-8')

key = b'\x01' * 16  #128-bit key
# plaintext = b'\x06' * 8  #64-bit plaintext
message = "I love cybersecurity"

round_keys = key_expansion(key)
for i, rk in enumerate(round_keys):
    print(f"Round Key {i}: {rk.hex()}")

# Encrypt
# ciphertext = encrypt_block_8(plaintext, round_keys)
ciphertext = encrypt_message(message, key)
print("Ciphertext:", ciphertext)

# Decrypt
# decrypted_text = decrypt_block_8(ciphertext, round_keys)
decrypted_text = decrypt_message(ciphertext, key)
print("Decrypted Text:", decrypted_text)






You should be able to inspect and record the state of the cipher before and after each round of encryption, and then do the same for decryption and determine at which round the decryption fails. This should allow to find precisely which transformation is not working as expected.

FWIW: I hope you're not planning to use this custom algorithm for anything serious. Block ciphers are not easy to design securely (just look at the number of broken ones in the past). It's fun to implement these; not so fun if they get broken later.

As for the actual problem: your description of the cipher doesn't seem to match the actual cipher at all. You claim it's a Feistel design, but the actual design looks like a 64-bit version of AES with no evidence that you're actually mixing two 64-bit blocks together. If your individual operations invert properly, you might to pay very careful attention to the number of rounds you're doing in the encryption and decryption process and the exact sequence of operations that are performed in each.
