encryption and decryption using python
I am supposed to encrypt text using the encryption code then decrypt it using the decryption code and get the original text. however, my code has something wrong with it because I keep getting different text when I try to decrypt. please help guysss.
btw this is an algorithm we designed for an assignment and not something already there.
This is my encryption algorithm code:
import binascii
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

# Helper Functions for Conversion
def text_to_hex(text):
    """Convert plain text to hexadecimal."""
    return binascii.hexlify(text.encode()).decode()

def hex_to_binary(hex_string):
    """Convert hexadecimal to binary."""
    return bin(int(hex_string, 16))[2:].zfill(len(hex_string) * 4)

# Constants 
NUM_ROUNDS = 16
BLOCK_SIZE = 256
HALF_BLOCK_SIZE = 128
NUM_SUBKEYS = 36

# Helper Functions
def rotate_left(value, shift, size=8):
    """Rotate bits to the left."""
    return ((value << shift) & (2**size - 1)) | (value >> (size - shift))

def rotate_right(value, shift, size=8):
    """Rotate bits to the right."""
    return (value >> shift) | ((value << (size - shift)) & (2**size - 1))

def xor_blocks(block1, block2):
    """XOR two blocks."""
    return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(block1, block2))

def gf_mult(a, b):
    """Multiply two numbers in GF(2^8)."""
    p = 0
    for _ in range(8):
        if b & 1:
            p ^= a
        carry = a & 0x80
        a <<= 1
        if carry:
            a ^= 0x1b
        b >>= 1
    return p & 0xFF

def mix_columns(state):
    """Mix Columns operation using the provided constant matrix."""
    matrix = np.array([
        [0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x01],
        [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01],
        [0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03],
        [0x03, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02]
    ], dtype=np.uint8)
    
    new_state = np.zeros_like(state)
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            new_state[i, j] = gf_mult(matrix[i, 0], state[0, j]) ^ \
                              gf_mult(matrix[i, 1], state[1, j]) ^ \
                              gf_mult(matrix[i, 2], state[2, j]) ^ \
                              gf_mult(matrix[i, 3], state[3, j])
    return new_state

def key_expansion(master_key):
    """Generate subkeys from the master key."""
    subkeys = []
    key_len = len(master_key)
    num_subkeys_needed = NUM_SUBKEYS * 16  # Total bytes needed for all subkeys
    
    # Repeat the master key enough times to fill the needed length
    expanded_key = (master_key * ((num_subkeys_needed // key_len) + 1))[:num_subkeys_needed]
    
    for i in range(NUM_SUBKEYS):
        subkey = bytearray(expanded_key[i * 16:(i + 1) * 16])
        subkeys.append(subkey)
    
    print(f"Subkeys: {subkeys}")  # Debug statement to check subkeys
    return subkeys


# Modify S-Box based on master key
def modify_sbox(base_sbox, master_key):
    """Modify the S-box based on the master key."""
    key_hex = binascii.hexlify(master_key).decode()
    if any(char in '01234567' for char in key_hex):
        return [base_sbox[(i + 1) % 256] for i in range(256)]  # Left shift S-box
    else:
        return [base_sbox[(i - 1) % 256] for i in range(256)]  # Right shift S-box

# Feistel Function
def feistel_function(input_block, subkey1, subkey2, sbox):
    """Feistel function with key-dependent S-boxes."""
    combined = bytearray(16)
    
    # Combine bits from input and subkey1 using XOR
    for i in range(16):
        combined[i] = input_block[i] ^ subkey1[i]
    
    # Apply S-Box substitution
    for i in range(16):
        combined[i] = sbox[combined[i]]
    
    # Mix Columns (AES Mix Columns)
    state = np.array(combined).reshape(4, 4)
    state = mix_columns(state)
    combined = state.flatten()
    
    # XOR with subkey2
    output = bytearray(16)
    for i in range(16):
        output[i] = combined[i] ^ subkey2[i]
    
    return output

# Encryption Function
def encrypt_block(plaintext, master_key):
    """Encrypt a 256-bit plaintext block."""
    # Split plaintext into two 128-bit halves
    LPT = plaintext[:16]
    RPT = plaintext[16:]
    
    # Key Expansion
    subkeys = key_expansion(master_key)
    
    # Modify S-box
    base_sbox = [
        0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76,
        0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0,
        0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15,
        0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75,
        0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84,
        0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf,
        0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8,
        0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2,
        0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73,
        0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e, 0x0b, 0xdb,
        0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79,
        0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08, 
        0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a, 
        0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e, 
        0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf, 
        0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16
    ]
    sbox = modify_sbox(base_sbox, master_key)
    
    # Initial XOR with subkeys
    LPT = xor_blocks(LPT, subkeys[0])
    RPT = xor_blocks(RPT, subkeys[1])
    RPT = bytearray(rotate_left(b, 1) for b in RPT)
    
    # Feistel Rounds
    for round in range(NUM_ROUNDS):
        # Feistel function
        temp = feistel_function(LPT, subkeys[2*round + 4], subkeys[2*round + 5], sbox)
        
        # XOR LPT with Feistel function output
        RPT = xor_blocks(RPT, temp)
        
        # Right shift LPT
        LPT = bytearray(rotate_right(b, 1) for b in LPT)
        
        # Swap LPT and RPT
        LPT, RPT = RPT, LPT
    
    # After the 16 rounds switch LPT & RPT
    LPT, RPT = RPT, LPT
    
    # Final XOR with subkeys
    LPT = xor_blocks(LPT, subkeys[2])
    RPT = xor_blocks(RPT, subkeys[3])
    
    # Combine LPT and RPT
    ciphertext = LPT + RPT
    
    return ciphertext

# GUI Application
def encrypt_text():
    plaintext = entry_plaintext.get()
    
    # Ensure the plaintext is 256 bits (32 bytes)
    if len(plaintext) > 32:
        plaintext = plaintext[:32]
    elif len(plaintext) < 32:
        plaintext = plaintext.ljust(32, '\0')  # pad with null bytes
    
    # Convert plaintext to hexadecimal
    plaintext_hex = text_to_hex(plaintext)
    
    # Convert hex to bytes
    plaintext_bytes = bytes.fromhex(plaintext_hex)
    
    # Define the master key (can be changed)
    master_key = "attack_on_titans_AOS_attack_on_titans_AOS".encode()  # 256-bit master key
    
    # Encryption
    ciphertext = encrypt_block(plaintext_bytes, master_key)
    
    # Display ciphertext in hexadecimal format
    entry_ciphertext.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_ciphertext.insert(0, ciphertext.hex())

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Encrypt Text")

# Create and place the components in the window
label_plaintext = tk.Label(root, text="Plaintext:")
label_plaintext.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_plaintext = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry_plaintext.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

label_ciphertext = tk.Label(root, text="Ciphertext:")
label_ciphertext.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_ciphertext = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry_ciphertext.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

button_encrypt = tk.Button(root, text="Encrypt", command=encrypt_text)
button_encrypt.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# Run the GUI event loop
root.mainloop()


and this is my decryption algorithm code:
import binascii
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk

# Helper Functions for Conversion
def text_to_hex(text):
    """Convert plain text to hexadecimal."""
    return binascii.hexlify(text.encode()).decode()

def hex_to_binary(hex_string):
    """Convert hexadecimal to binary."""
    return bin(int(hex_string, 16))[2:].zfill(len(hex_string) * 4)

# Constants 
NUM_ROUNDS = 16
BLOCK_SIZE = 256
HALF_BLOCK_SIZE = 128
NUM_SUBKEYS = 36

# Helper Functions
def rotate_left(value, shift, size=8):
    """Rotate bits to the left."""
    return ((value << shift) & (2**size - 1)) | (value >> (size - shift))

def rotate_right(value, shift, size=8):
    """Rotate bits to the right."""
    return (value >> shift) | ((value << (size - shift)) & (2**size - 1))

def xor_blocks(block1, block2):
    """XOR two blocks."""
    return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(block1, block2))

def gf_mult(a, b):
    """Multiply two numbers in GF(2^8)."""
    p = 0
    for _ in range(8):
        if b & 1:
            p ^= a
        carry = a & 0x80
        a <<= 1
        if carry:
            a ^= 0x1b
        b >>= 1
    return p & 0xFF

def mix_columns(state):
    """Mix Columns operation using the provided constant matrix."""
    matrix = np.array([
        [0x0e, 0x0b, 0x0d, 0x09],
        [0x09, 0x0e, 0x0b, 0x0d],
        [0x0d, 0x09, 0x0e, 0x0b],
        [0x0b, 0x0d, 0x09, 0x0e]
    ], dtype=np.uint8)
    
    new_state = np.zeros_like(state)
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(4):
            new_state[i, j] = gf_mult(matrix[i, 0], state[0, j]) ^ \
                              gf_mult(matrix[i, 1], state[1, j]) ^ \
                              gf_mult(matrix[i, 2], state[2, j]) ^ \
                              gf_mult(matrix[i, 3], state[3, j])
    return new_state

def key_expansion(master_key):
    """Generate subkeys from the master key."""
    subkeys = []
    key_len = len(master_key)
    num_subkeys_needed = NUM_SUBKEYS * 16  # Total bytes needed for all subkeys
    
    # Repeat the master key enough times to fill the needed length
    expanded_key = (master_key * ((num_subkeys_needed // key_len) + 1))[:num_subkeys_needed]
    
    for i in range(NUM_SUBKEYS):
        subkey = bytearray(expanded_key[i * 16:(i + 1) * 16])
        subkeys.append(subkey)
    
    print(f"Subkeys: {subkeys}")  # Debug statement to check subkeys
    return subkeys


# Modify S-Box based on master key
def modify_sbox(base_sbox, master_key):
    """Modify the S-box based on the master key."""
    key_hex = binascii.hexlify(master_key).decode()
    if any(char in '01234567' for char in key_hex):
        return [base_sbox[(i + 1) % 256] for i in range(256)]  # Left shift S-box
    else:
        return [base_sbox[(i - 1) % 256] for i in range(256)]  # Right shift S-box


# Inverse S-Box
inv_sbox = [
    0x52, 0x09, 0x6A, 0xD5, 0x30, 0x36, 0xA5, 0x38, 0xBF, 0x40, 0xA3, 0x9E, 0x81, 0xF3, 0xD7, 0xFB,
    0x7C, 0xE3, 0x39, 0x82, 0x9B, 0x2F, 0xFF, 0x87, 0x34, 0x8E, 0x43, 0x44, 0xC4, 0xDE, 0xE9, 0xCB,
    0x54, 0x7B, 0x94, 0x32, 0xA6, 0xC2, 0x23, 0x3D, 0xEE, 0x4C, 0x95, 0x0B, 0x42, 0xFA, 0xC3, 0x4E,
    0x08, 0x2E, 0xA1, 0x66, 0x28, 0xD9, 0x24, 0xB2, 0x76, 0x5B, 0xA2, 0x49, 0x6D, 0x8B, 0xD1, 0x25,
    0x72, 0xF8, 0xF6, 0x64, 0x86, 0x68, 0x98, 0x16, 0xD4, 0xA4, 0x5C, 0xCC, 0x5D, 0x65, 0xB6, 0x92,
    0x6C, 0x70, 0x48, 0x50, 0xFD, 0xED, 0xB9, 0xDA, 0x5E, 0x15, 0x46, 0x57, 0xA7, 0x8D, 0x9D, 0x84,
    0x90, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0x00, 0x8C, 0xBC, 0xD3, 0x0A, 0xF7, 0xE4, 0x58, 0x05, 0xB8, 0xB3, 0x45, 0x06,
    0xD0, 0x2C, 0x1E, 0x8F, 0xCA, 0x3F, 0x0F, 0x02, 0xC1, 0xAF, 0xBD, 0x03, 0x01, 0x13, 0x8A, 0x6B,
    0x3A, 0x91, 0x11, 0x41, 0x4F, 0x67, 0xDC, 0xEA, 0x97, 0xF2, 0xCF, 0xCE, 0xF0, 0xB4, 0xE6, 0x73,
    0x96, 0xAC, 0x74, 0x22, 0xE7, 0xAD, 0x35, 0x85, 0xE2, 0xF9, 0x37, 0xE8, 0x1C, 0x75, 0xDF, 0x6E,
    0x47, 0xF1, 0x1A, 0x71, 0x1D, 0x29, 0xC5, 0x89, 0x6F, 0xB7, 0x62, 0x0E, 0xAA, 0x18, 0xBE, 0x1B,
    0xFC, 0x56, 0x3E, 0x4B, 0xC6, 0xD2, 0x79, 0x20, 0x9A, 0xDB, 0xC0, 0xFE, 0x78, 0xCD, 0x5A, 0xF4,
    0x1F, 0xDD, 0xA8, 0x33, 0x88, 0x07, 0xC7, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x12, 0x10, 0x59, 0x27, 0x80, 0xEC, 0x5F, 
    0x60, 0x51, 0x7F, 0xA9, 0x19, 0xB5, 0x4A, 0x0D, 0x2D, 0xE5, 0x7A, 0x9F, 0x93, 0xC9, 0x9C, 0xEF, 
    0xA0, 0xE0, 0x3B, 0x4D, 0xAE, 0x2A, 0xF5, 0xB0, 0xC8, 0xEB, 0xBB, 0x3C, 0x83, 0x53, 0x99, 0x61, 
    0x17, 0x2B, 0x04, 0x7E, 0xBA, 0x77, 0xD6, 0x26, 0xE1, 0x69, 0x14, 0x63, 0x55, 0x21, 0x0C, 0x7D
]

# Inverse Feistel Function
def inverse_feistel_function(input_block, subkey1, subkey2, sbox):
    """Inverse Feistel function with key-dependent S-boxes."""
    combined = bytearray(16)
    
    # Combine bits from input and subkey2 using XOR
    for i in range(16):
        combined[i] = input_block[i] ^ subkey2[i]
    
    # Mix Columns (AES Mix Columns)
    state = np.array(combined).reshape(4, 4)
    state = mix_columns(state)
    combined = state.flatten()
    
    # Apply inverse S-Box substitution
    for i in range(16):
        combined[i] = sbox[combined[i]]
    
    # XOR with subkey1
    output = bytearray(16)
    for i in range(16):
        output[i] = combined[i] ^ subkey1[i]
    
    return output

# Decryption Function
def decrypt_block(ciphertext, master_key):
    """Decrypt a 256-bit ciphertext block."""
    # Split ciphertext into two 128-bit halves
    LPT = ciphertext[:16]
    RPT = ciphertext[16:]
    
    # Key Expansion
    subkeys = key_expansion(master_key)
    
    # Modify inverse S-box based on master key
    modified_inv_sbox = modify_sbox(inv_sbox, master_key)
    
    # Initial XOR with subkeys
    LPT = xor_blocks(LPT, subkeys[2])
    RPT = xor_blocks(RPT, subkeys[3])
    
    # Swap LPT and RPT
    LPT, RPT = RPT, LPT
    
    # Feistel Rounds (reverse order)
    for round in reversed(range(NUM_ROUNDS)):
        J = 1 + ((round % 4) + (round // 4))
        
        # Right shift LPT
        LPT = bytearray(rotate_left(b, J) for b in LPT)
        
        # Inverse Feistel function
        temp = inverse_feistel_function(LPT, subkeys[2*round + 4], subkeys[2*round + 5], modified_inv_sbox)
        
        # XOR RPT with output of inverse Feistel function
        RPT = xor_blocks(RPT, temp)
        
        # Swap LPT and RPT
        LPT, RPT = RPT, LPT
    
    # Final operations
    RPT = bytearray(rotate_right(b, 1) for b in RPT)
    RPT = xor_blocks(RPT, subkeys[1])
    LPT = xor_blocks(LPT, subkeys[0])
    
    # Combine LPT and RPT
    plaintext = LPT + RPT
    
    return plaintext

# GUI Application for Decryption
def decrypt_text():
    ciphertext = entry_ciphertext.get()
    
    # Convert ciphertext from hexadecimal to bytes
    ciphertext_bytes = bytes.fromhex(ciphertext)
    
    # Define the master key (must be the same as used in encryption)
    master_key = "attack_on_titans_AOS_attack_on_titans_AOS".encode()  # 256-bit master key
    
    # Decryption
    plaintext_bytes = decrypt_block(ciphertext_bytes, master_key)
    
    # Convert plaintext bytes to text, ignoring invalid bytes
    plaintext = plaintext_bytes.decode('utf-8', 'ignore').rstrip('\0')
    
    # Display plaintext
    entry_plaintext.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_plaintext.insert(0, plaintext)

# Create the main window for decryption
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Decrypt Text")

# Create and place the components in the window
label_ciphertext = tk.Label(root, text="Ciphertext:")
label_ciphertext.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_ciphertext = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry_ciphertext.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

label_plaintext = tk.Label(root, text="Plaintext:")
label_plaintext.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_plaintext = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
entry_plaintext.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

button_decrypt = tk.Button(root, text="Decrypt", command=decrypt_text)
button_decrypt.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)

# Run the GUI event loop
root.mainloop()


I was trying to get the original text I encrypted but I got different text.

What does AI have to do with encryption/decryption?

This is lots of code. Can you explain the encryption algorithm you're trying to implement?

Have you tested all the helper functions?

None of the tkinter code is relevant to the question. Please reduce to a [mre].

Please don't include duplicate code.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78775407/cannot-decrypt-the-encrypted-message#comment138888448_78775407
